# How to make the result of 2 SELECT statements appear in adjacent columns in SQL oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

I am using SQL oracle. I have a table in which I have queried for two types of items:

1st query:

```
SELECT SUM(OLI.QUANTITY) AS "SPECIALITY ITEMS ORDERED - SEPT 2019"
FROM ORDER_LINE_ITEM OLI, CUSTOMER_ORDER CO
WHERE CO.ORDER_ID = OLI.ORDER_ID
AND OLI.ORDER_KIND = 'SPL'
AND CO.ORDER_DATE >= TO_DATE('01 SEPTEMBER 2019', 'DD MONTH YYYY')
AND CO.ORDER_DATE <= TO_DATE('30 SEPTEMBER 2019', 'DD MONTH YYYY')
```

Output:

```
SPECIALITY ITEMS ORDERED - SEPT 2019
------------------------------------
            111
```

2nd Query:

```
SELECT SUM(OLI.QUANTITY) AS "BUILD YOUR OWN ITEMS ORDERED - SEPT 2019"
FROM ORDER_LINE_ITEM OLI, CUSTOMER_ORDER CO
WHERE CO.ORDER_ID = OLI.ORDER_ID
AND OLI.ORDER_KIND = 'BYO'
AND CO.ORDER_DATE >= TO_DATE('01 SEPTEMBER 2019', 'DD MONTH YYYY')
AND CO.ORDER_DATE <= TO_DATE('30 SEPTEMBER 2019', 'DD MONTH YYYY')
```

Output:

```
BUILD YOUR OWN ITEMS ORDERED - SEPT 2019
----------------------------------------
            49
```

I want to display the result of the 2 queries and reflect the output as 2 columns adjacent to each other as below:

```
SPECIALITY ITEMS ORDERED - SEPT 2019    |    BUILD YOUR OWN ITEMS ORDERED - SEPT 2019
------------------------------------    |    ----------------------------------------
            111                         |                     49
```

How do I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this:

```
select sum(case when oli.order_kind = 'SPL' then oli.quantity else 0 end) result_1,
       sum(case when oli.order_kind = 'BYO' then oli.quantity else 0 end) result_2
from order_line_item oli, customer_order co
where co.order_id = oli.order_id
  and oli.order_kind in ('SPL', 'BYO')
  and co.order_date >= to_date('01 SEPTEMBER 2019', 'DD MONTH YYYY')
  and co.order_date <= to_date('30 SEPTEMBER 2019', 'DD MONTH YYYY')
```

---

Another option (not that I'd recommend it, but - it's an option) is to re-use your queries as follows:

```
select 
  (select sum(oli.quantity)
   from order_line_item oli, customer_order co
   where co.order_id = oli.order_id
     and oli.order_kind = 'SPL'
     and co.order_date >= to_date('01 SEPTEMBER 2019', 'DD MONTH YYYY')
     and co.order_date <= to_date('30 SEPTEMBER 2019', 'DD MONTH YYYY')
  ) result_1,
--
  (select sum(oli.quantity)
   from order_line_item oli, customer_order co
   where co.order_id = oli.order_id
     and oli.order_kind = 'BYO'
     and co.order_date >= to_date('01 SEPTEMBER 2019', 'DD MONTH YYYY')
     and co.order_date <= to_date('30 SEPTEMBER 2019', 'DD MONTH YYYY')
  ) result_2
from dual;
```

---

Or, using CTE:

```
with 
t_first as 
  (select sum(oli.quantity) result_1
   from order_line_item oli, customer_order co
   where co.order_id = oli.order_id
     and oli.order_kind = 'SPL'
     and co.order_date >= to_date('01 SEPTEMBER 2019', 'DD MONTH YYYY')
     and co.order_date <= to_date('30 SEPTEMBER 2019', 'DD MONTH YYYY')
  ),
--
t_second as
(select sum(oli.quantity) result_2
   from order_line_item oli, customer_order co
   where co.order_id = oli.order_id
     and oli.order_kind = 'BYO'
     and co.order_date >= to_date('01 SEPTEMBER 2019', 'DD MONTH YYYY')
     and co.order_date <= to_date('30 SEPTEMBER 2019', 'DD MONTH YYYY')
  ) 
select a.result_1, b.result_2
from t_first a cross join t_second b;
```

---

Finally, although Oracle works just fine using joins you used, it is nowadays recommended to follow the most recent ANSI syntax and explicit joins, i.e.

```
select ...
from order_line_item oli join customer_order co on co.order_id = oli.order_id
where ...
```

Comment: In the 1st code statement, the code runs properly even without inserting the 5th line "and oli.order_kind = 'SPL'." Is it necessary to include this line?

Comment: (Sorry, went to the cinema) Actually, it should have probably been `and oli.order_kind in ('SPL', 'BYO')` so that query looks only at those values. But - yes - you'd get the correct result because `case` would eliminate other values. I have now fixed it.